# How to use for loop inside a TTask threadin delphi 10

Tags: delphi, concurrency, delphi-10-seattle, ppl-delphi

How to use for loop inside a TTask properly? i keep getting only the last item of ListBox1 in the memo, for example if i have 5 items in ListBox1, i get the last item of ListBox1 5 times in memo1 !, what is wrong with code ?

```
var
  i: Integer;
  lPath: string;
begin
  for i := 0 to ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    lPath := ListBox1.Items.Strings[i];
    TTask.Create(
      procedure
      var
        lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
        IdSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
      begin
        lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);

        TThread.Synchronize(nil,
          procedure
          begin
            Form1.Caption := 'Task Running...';
          end
        );

        try
          lHTTP.ReadTimeout := 30000;
          lHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
          IdSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(lHTTP);
          IdSSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
          IdSSL.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
          lHTTP.IOHandler := IdSSL;
        Finally
          try
            lHTTP.Get('http://website.com/'+lPath, TStream(nil));
          Finally
            lHTTP.Free;
          end;
        end;

        TThread.Synchronize(nil,
          procedure
          begin
            Memo1.Lines.Add(lPath);
           end
        );

      end
    ).Start;

  end;
end;
```

Comment: @Phil: This has nothing to do with OTL. It's the new Parallel Processing functionality in Delphi 10 Seattle/Berlin.

Comment: it might be, but i dont know how to apply it to my code @PhilRoss

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the adapted code:

```
// Current method:
procedure TMyForm.XYZ
var
  i: Integer;
  lPath: string;
begin
  for i := 0 to ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    lPath := ListBox1.Items.Strings[i];
    StartDownloadTask(lPath);
  end;
end;

// Put task creation in separate method:
procedure TMyForm.StartDownloadTask(lPath: string)
begin
    TTask.Create(
      procedure
      var
        lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
        IdSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
      begin
        lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);

        TThread.Synchronize(nil,
          procedure
          begin
            Form1.Caption := 'Task Running...';
          end
        );

        try
          lHTTP.ReadTimeout := 30000;
          lHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
          IdSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(lHTTP);
          IdSSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
          IdSSL.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
          lHTTP.IOHandler := IdSSL;
        Finally
          try
            lHTTP.Get('http://website.com/'+lPath, TStream(nil));
          Finally
            lHTTP.Free;
          end;
        end;

        TThread.Synchronize(nil,
          procedure
          begin
            Memo1.Lines.Add(lPath);
           end
        );

      end
    ).Start;
end;
```

For an explanation on the background see the explanation in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13349520/101087

Most important parts from the other answer:

> Note that variable capture captures variables—not values. If a
>   variable's value changes after being captured by constructing an
>   anonymous method, the value of the variable the anonymous method
>   captured changes too, because they are the same variable with the same
>   storage.
>
> To capture the *value* of the loop variable, wrap creation of the task
>   in a separate function: